# Uncaught ReferenceError: addRecord is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, dom

when i click on the add record button it doesn't work and then it gives me an uncaught reference error, but if i load one of the jquery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js scripts in the browser, it shows the button working perfectly.
any suggestions please?

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
{%load staticfiles%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

okay.html

```
...
{% extends "s/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

{% block s_base %}
{{ block.super }}
<script>
alert('Helloo');
function addRecord(){
    console.log('hhhffhgfhdf');
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
            <div> <a href="javascript:void(0);"  ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord();"> Add New Advert </button></a></div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you don't want to use Jquery, I suppose.

In this case, you can add your script close to the  tag and and call the addRecord function like:

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclic k= function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addRecord()
}

}
```

There's several ways of doing it but this is just an idea. remember to remove the `onclick` attibute from your html button

Comment: Thanks the error isn't showing anymore and it works just fine!